# Machine Learning Method to Predict Continuous Target Variable with Text Data Using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining

## Purpose

I have a surgery dataset with surgery id (i.e.,`oid`), the procedure names (`o3.name.procedure`), and the actual duration (i.e. `d1.case`). There could be multiple procedures in one surgery, so one surgery id can be associated with multiple procedures names. **My goal is to predict the expected case duration using text analysis of procedure names. I am following a tutorial**:  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/machine-learning-text-data-using-r . But I have **a continuous target variable (duration) instead of indicator target variable (0 or 1)**. Below dataset followed the data preparation steps in the above tutorial, but I was wondering **what method I can use to predict the continuous target variable** after preparing the text data.

The following code 'Example Dataset' generates the text data and processes them following the tutorial.  In the original dataset, there are 58K unique procedure names for total 155K observations associated with 77K surgeries. Each surgery may contain 1 to 10 procedures. Each procedure name may contain main procedure name and additional details associated with the particular surgery. The main procedure name is not separated and is not identified in the dataset.

## Example Dataset

```
  procedures <-
    c("EXCISION OF MULTIPLE EXTERNAL PAPILLAE OR TAGS, ANUS   **ANAL FISTULOTOMY, EXCISION OF ANAL TAGS**", 
      "DAVINCI-LAPAROSCOPY,SURGICAL, W/TOTAL HYSTERECTOMY, FOR UTERUS 250 G OR LESS W/REMOVAL OF TUBE(S)/OVARY(S)**ROBOTIC SURPRACERVICAL HYSTERECTOMY WITH BILATERAL SALPINGECTOMY, ROBOTIC ASSISTED SACRAL COLPOPEXY, POSTERIOR REPAIR, TVT SLING, CYSTO**", 
      "INCISION & DRAINAGE, OPEN, OF DEEP ABSCESS, POSTERIOR SPINE; CERVICAL, THORACIC, OR CERVICOTHORACIC (POSTERIOR CERVICAL WOUND WASHOUT WITH WOUND VAC PLACEMENT)", 
      "EXCISION OF CYST/TUMOR, BREAST TISSUE, DUCT/NIPPLE/AREOLAR LESION, OPEN, MALE/FEMALE, ONE OR MORE LESION  **LEFT BREAST EXCISIONAL BIOPSY WITH LACRIMAL PROBE**", 
      "POSTERIOR SEGMENTAL INSTRUMENTATION; 13 OR MORE VERTEBRAL SEGEMENTS (LIST SEP. IN ADD. TO PRIMARY PROC.) (posterior spinal fusion with instrumentation T4-T1, cell saver)", 
      "POSTERIOR NON-SEGMENTAL INSTRUMENTATION (HARRINGTON ROD,PEDICLE FIX, ATLANTOAXIAL FIX)(+) (L4-5 POST DECOMP/ PSIF/TPLIF)", 
      "COLPOPEXY, VAGINAL, INTRA-PERITONEAL APPROACH (UTEROSACRAL, LEVATOR MYORRHAHPY);LAVH BSO VAGINAL VAULT SUSPENSION,POSSIBLE A&P REPAIR", 
      "EXCISION, TUMOR OR VASCULAR MALFORMATION, SOFT TISSUE OF HAND OR FINGER, SUBCUTANEOUS; LESS THAN 1.5 CM", 
      "RECONSTRUCTIVE REPAIR PECTUS EXCAVATUM OR CARINATUM; MINIMALLY INVASIVE (NUSS PROCEDURE), W/THORACOSCOPY  ** NUSS REPAIR OF PECTUS EXCAVATUM**", 
      "SURGICAL; COLECTOMY, PARTIAL, W/ REMOVAL TERMINAL ILEUM WITH ILEOCOLOSTOMY  **OPEN RIGHT COLECTOMY** ", 
      "LAPAROSCOPY, MYOMECTOMY, EXCISION; 5 OR MORE INTRAMURAL MYOMAS >250 GRAMS**LAPAROSCOPIC MYOMECTOMY**", 
      "EXPLORATORY LAPAROTOMY, EXPLORATORY CELIOTOMY WITH OR WITHOUT BIOPSY - WASHOUT **Exploratory laparotomy with abdominal washout, opening of the vaginal cuff with placement of 30' mushroom drain to vagina**", 
      "LUMBAR LAMINOTOMY W/PARTL FACETECTOMY/FORAMINOTOMY/HERNIATED DISKECTOMY, RE-EXPLORE, 1 INTERSPACE;(C-ARM) (REVISION RIGHT L5-S1 MICRODISCECTOMY)", 
      "PERCUTANEOUS SKELETAL FIXATION OF POSTERIOR PELVIC BONE FX/DISLOCATION,FOR FX PATTERNS/DISRUPT PELVIC RING", 
      "LAPAROSCOPY; W/FULGURATION OF OVIDUCTS (W/WO TRANSECTION)(TUBAL LIGATION) **LAPAROSCOPIC BILATERAL TUBAL LIGATION **", 
      "THROMBECTOMY, OPEN, ARTERIOVENOUS FISTULA W/O REVISION, AUTOGENOUS/NONAUTOGENOUS DIALYSIS GRAFT (C-ARM) **RIGHT THIGH ARTERIOVENOUS GRAFT DECLOT WITH VENOGRAM**BALLON ANGIOPLASTY REVISION**", 
      "CORONOIDECTOMY (MANDIBLE)", "LAMINECTOMY W/DECOMPRESSION, SINGLE VERTEBRAL SEGMENT; LUMBAR**L4-5 AND L5-S1 OPEN DECOMPRESSION, FROM THE LEFT**", 
      "PELVIC EXAM UNDER ANESTHESIA (OTHER THAN LOCAL)**PELVIC EXAM UNDER ANESTHESIA;  POSSIBLE CERVICAL BIOPSY**", 
      "LAMINOTOMY(HEMILAMINECTOMY) W/DECOMPRESSION OF NERVE ROOT(S),INCLUD PART FACETECTOMY, 1 INTERSPACE LUMBAR (REVISION RIGHT L4-5 MICRODISCECTOMY)", 
      "DESTRUCTION BY NEUROLYTIC AGENT,PARAVERTEBRAL FACET JOINT NERVE W/FLURO; LUMBAR OR SACRAL, EACH ADD`L LEVEL (64636 X 2)", 
      "CYSTOURETHROSCOPY, W/FULGURATION/RESECTION OF; MEDIUM BLADDER TUMOR(S)(2.0-5.0 CM)*CYSTOSCOPY,TRANSURETHRAL RESECTION OF BLADDER TUMOR,POSSIBLE LEFT URETERAL STENT PLACEMENT*", 
      "TREATMENT OF MISSED ABORTION SECOND TRIMESTER", "UNLISTED PROCEDURE, DENTOALVEOLAR STRUCTURES*DENTAL RESTORATION*", 
      "REVASCULARIZATION,ENDOVASCULAR,OPEN OR PERCUTANEOUS,FEMORAL,POPLITEAL ARTERY(S),UNILATERAL,WITH TRANSLUMINAL STENT PLACEMENT(S),INCLUDES ANGIOPLASTY WITHIN THE SAME VESSEL,WHEN PERFORMED**RIGHT LEG INTERVENTION**", 
      "EXPLORATION OF PENETRATING WOUND; NECK*left neck exploration*", 
      "OPEN TREATMENT OF CLAVICULAR FRACTURE, INCLUDES INTERNAL FIXATION,WHEN PERFORMED**OPEN REDUCTION AND INTERNAL FIXATION OF RIGHT CLAVICLE**", 
      "INSERTION OF INFLATABLE URETHRAL/BLADDER NECK SPHINCTER, INCLUDING PUMP, RESERVOIR AND CUFF **PLACEMENT OF ARTIFICIAL URINARY SPHINCTER**", 
      "Surgical fixation of left humerus", "COLPOCLEISIS (LE FORT TYPE)**CYSTOSCOPY, COLPOCLEISIS (LEFORT TYPE)**"
    )
  
  set.seed(10002)
  procedure <-
    sample(procedures, 1000, replace = T)
  
  set.seed(10003)
  case <- sample(1:300, 1000, replace=T)

  set.seed(10005)
  duration <- sample(0:200, 1000, replace=T)
  
  
  df <-
    data.frame(case, procedure, duration) %>% 
    rename(
      oid = case,
      o3.name.procedure = procedure,
      d1.case = duration
    ) %>% 
    group_by(oid) %>% # I collapse the procedures names by each surgery id
    summarise(
      word = paste0(o3.name.procedure, collapse = "|"),
      no = length(o3.name.procedure),
      d1.case = mean(d1.case)
    ) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(d1.case)) 

    
    ## Preparing Data for Modeling
    # Step 1 - Create the Text Corpus 
    corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(df$word))
    corpus[[1]][1]
    df$d1.case[1]
    
    # Step 2 - Conversion to Lowercase
    corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
    corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower)
    corpus[[1]][1]
    
    # Step 3 - Removing Punctuation
    corpus = tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
    corpus[[1]][1]
    
    # Step 4 - Removing Stopwords
    corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("w", "wo", "wwo", stopwords("english")))
    corpus[[1]][1]
    
    # Step 5 - Stemming
    corpus = tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
    corpus[[1]][1]
    
    ## Create Document Term Matrix
    frequencies = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
    sparse = removeSparseTerms(frequencies, 0.995)
    
    ### The final data preparation step is to convert the matrix into a data frame, 
    ### a format widely used in 'R' for predictive modeling. 
    tSparse = as.data.frame(as.matrix(sparse))
    colnames(tSparse) = make.names(colnames(tSparse)) 
    tSparse$duration = df$d1.case # adding the dependent variable
    
    ## Now we are ready for building the predictive model. 
    ## set the baseline accuracy --- note: it works for 0 and 1 indicator dependent variable
    prop.table(table(tSparse$duration))
    
    ## Creating Training and Test Data for Machine Learning
    set.seed(100)
    split = sample.split(tSparse$duration, SplitRatio = 0.7)
    # keeps 70% of the data for training the model. 
    trainSparse = subset(tSparse, split==TRUE)
    testSparse = subset(tSparse, split==FALSE)
    

}
```

The post has been migrated from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211593/machine-learning-method-to-predict-continuous-target-variable-with-text-data-usi?noredirect=1#comment120555438_68211593

Comment: It sounds like you would be more comfortable solving this problem if the target were categorical (a "classification" problem). How would you approach such a problem?

Comment: Hi @Dave . If the target is dummy (0 or 1), then random forest in the tutorial would be used.  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/machine-learning-text-data-using-r .

Comment: Why not use a random forest with the continuous target variable?

Comment: @Dave , would it be Random Forest without making the target variable factors? For example, the tutorial factorize the target variable, but I can use the continuous target directly.  ` RF_model = randomForest(duration ~ ., data=trainSparse)` then `predictRF = predict(RF_model, newdata=testSparse)` Does it sound to be correct?

Comment: Random forest can do regression to predict a continuous variable.

Comment: @Dave I may be lack of basic knowledge. I will study random forest regression and ask a more clear question. Thank you for your comments!